# Rospy callback attribute error

Tags: ros, rospy, subscribe, message

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Am following a youtube tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DLVyc9hOvk8) with my own code:

**Executable:**

```
import rospy
from tf2_msgs.msg import TFMessage
import math #mathsssss
def callback(msg): #global cariable
    x = msg.transforms.transform.translation.x
    y = msg.transforms.transform.translation.y
    rospy.loginfo('x: {}, y: {}'.format(x,y))
def main():
    rospy.init_node('location_monitor')  #makes this code into a ROS node
    rospy.Subscriber("/tf", TFMessage, callback)
    # to sub: give (name of topic, messageclass, callback you want to do
    rospy.spin() # loop
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**Shell returns:**

```
[ERROR] [1511523182.758203]: bad callback: <function callback at 0x7f1cd923e668>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/topics.py", line 750, in _invoke_callback
    cb(msg)
  File "/home/username/catkin_ws/src/pkgname/src/location_monitor_node.py", line 9, in callback
    x = msg.transforms.translation.x
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'translation'
```

Have searched other questions. Tried importing things from TFMessage, checking my capital letters, using it with .transform, and such. Nothing works.
Am pretty new to ROS.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/276625/rospy-callback-attribute-error/) by [anonymous32749](https://answers.ros.org/users/32749/anonymous32749/) on ROS Answers with karma: 62 on 2017-11-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

According to the documentation for `tf2_msgs/TFMessage` ([here](http://docs.ros.org/api/tf2_msgs/html/msg/TFMessage.html)), the `transforms` field is a list/array, so you'll need to index into it:

```
geometry_msgs/TransformStamped[] transforms
```

Something like `msg.transforms[0].transform.translation.x`.

But realise that you may receive multiple `TransformStamped`s in a single message, so always using the first might not be what you want.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-11-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-11-24**:
Note btw that subscribing to `/tf` like that is not typical usage. It's possible, but you might want to use the `tf2` infrastructure (with Listeners, Buffers, etc).

**Comment by [ramkumar](https://answers.ros.org/users/120370/ramkumar/) on 2022-10-13**:
hi,
i'm trying somthing similar to this.
i'm trying to use your suggestion (msg.transforms[0].transform.translation.x), but completely confused.
can you explain with small sample code !...
please!!